# Other method to call layers by options?

Tags: leaflet

I have this script the loop through all layers and do some stuff when its layer's option integer is found.

```
L.marker([1, 2], {
     divId: 1,
   })
   .addTo(map);

L.marker([2, 4], {
     divId: 2,
   })
   .addTo(map);

map.eachLayer(function(layer) {
    if(layer.options && layer.options.pane === "markerPane") {
        var a = layer.options.divId;
        var b = localStorage.getItem(saveID);
        if (b == a) //check if marker's option divID is = 1
        {
          //do something
        } else { 
          //do something
        }
    }

});
```

My question is, is there any method to call the layer with the option of divID:1? instead of looping each map layer

Comment: Store your markers in a data structure (e.g. a key-value map or hashmap), keyed by `divID`. Look up your markers in said data structure instead of looking them up in the map.

Comment: can you show a few code sample for that? not sure what to search

Comment: See https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/learn-all-about-data-structures-used-in-computer-science/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map , to start with.